# How to set up a C function that splits user input into multiple parts, and also splitting those smaller parts?

Tags: c, string, input, struct

I'm trying to develop a C function that takes a line of user input, say example this line:

```
1X 1X 3Y 1Z 1Z 1Z 1Z 2X 2X
```

(EDIT: This is just an arbitrary example of what the user will enter. In the actual program, they can enter anywhere between 1 and 48 digit-character pairs.)

The idea is that the user will insert this entire line, and it will split it up into 9 parts (each number and character pair is one part). Then, the number and the character pair will also be split from each other (I'm thinking for this part, they will both belong to a struct containing a numValue and charValue).

What can I use to split up the user's input? I'm relatively new to C.

Comment: scanf() will do it, though I don't like that function much.  Reading in the whole string then using sprintf() will do the work as well with a little care.  I'll leave it to others to fill out the details.  Or you can just google these functions and go from there.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)  What sort of interface do you envisage for this function?  Will the function allocate memory or will the user do so?  What should happen if there are only 8 digit-character pairs?  10 or more?  Can the numbers be larger than 9?  Less than zero?  Is it always one letter?  Is it always letters or could it be punctuation?  If you get `98` as a field, is the `8` the character?  Etc.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: you say `sprintf()` — did you mean `sscanf()`?  If you're quick, you can change it.

Comment: Not quick enough - lol.  But yeah - that was the idea.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thank you. Whoops, the 9 digit-character pairs was just an example. In the program, the user will be able to enter any amount of pairs, ranging from 1 pair to 48 pairs. (I will have error checking for cases of no pairs and cases of more than 48 pairs). The program has no way of knowing how many pairs the user will enter until it reads through all of the user's input.

As for the user inputting malformed data, I will check for that as well. I am **only** allowing for one digit and one character per pair. Every other combination will be ignored when reading the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function you could use to split the input string from the user is `strtok()` from the `#include <string.h>` library. Here is an example you can you use to split the input into nine parts.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main (){
    char word[] ="1X 1X 3Y 1Z 1Z 1Z 1Z 2X 2X";
    int i = 0;
    char *p = strtok(word, " ");
    char *array[9];

    while (p != NULL){
        array[i++] = p;
        p = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can do this again to split it up even further. To explain what `strtok` does I shall explain with this code :

`strtok(word, " ");`. `word` is the content of the string that will be modified and `" "` with be the delimiter for the string.

Comment: Thank you. I figured the code might make use of `strtok` twice. How should I change `line 5` and `line 8`? The user will be entering in the digit-character pairs, which the program will read. I think I could just read the user's entire input into a char array? As for `line 8`: how can I adjust the number of indexes dynamically? My first example was poorly worded -- as stated in my comment above, in the actual program the user decides how many pairs they want to enter.

Comment: @fallt_zz when you ask the user for number of pairs and store into a var like `i` you set `char *array[9];` to `char *array[i];`

Comment: @fallt_zz I hate to do this but I you appreciate this answer, then accept the answer

Comment: I'll accept the answer. I was hoping though that I wouldn't have to ask the user how many pairs they would be entering. I wanted it to be dynamic.

Comment: @fallt_zz check this out [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25746334/count-words-in-a-user-input-string-in-c) it should solve you problem

Comment: It's perfectly possible to handle the number of pairs 'dynamically'.  Since you say in another comment that the upper limit will be 48, change the occurrences of `9` to `MAX_PAIRS` and add `enum { MAX_PAIRS = 48 };` which will cover your current needs. Or you can go 'fully dynamic' and have the function allocate and reallocate memory. You should limit the loop so it doesn't go beyond that limit (no stack overflows on Stack Overflow). You can then pass that array to the function (it won't be a `main()` that does this splitting), or have the function allocate an array of the appropriate size.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler what online textbook did you read to gain all this knowledge on C?

Comment: @narusin: When I learned C, there weren't online text books — you had to buy the real paper books, and there was only one worth the money: Kernighan & Ritchie "The C Programmming Language" (1st Edition, but the qualifier wasn't relevant back then).  And there was the (7th Edition) Unix Programmer's Manual, of course — likewise paper.  Of course, some of the knowledge comes from reading since then, when there were online resources.  But 30+ years of coding in C has allowed me to see quite a lot.

Comment: @narusin: Actually, that's not quite fair.  There were a couple of other books of some use — The UNIX Programming Environment, C Traps and Pitfalls, C: A Reference Manual.  They're a bit later, but not much later, than K&R 1st Edn.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler What is the best textbook in your opinion for a less-experienced C user like me. I have been doing c for 2 months and I know the basic like arrays, pointers and `#define`. I want to develop my comprehension for this language.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143225/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-naru-sin).