# C - Using strtok to split an array of strings into an array of characters

Tags: c, arrays, string, strtok

This is a continuation of [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43747630/how-to-set-up-a-c-function-that-splits-user-input-into-multiple-parts-and-also/43747906?noredirect=1#comment74540612_43747906).

So far, I've successfully taken user input and stored it into strings. For example, I turned this:

```
1:E 2:B 2:B 2:B 4:G
```

Into this:
`1:E` `2:B` `2:B` `2:B` `4:G`
Which is an array of strings.

This is what I want to do next, but it's not working for me:
`1` `E` `2` `B` `2` `B` `2` `B` `4` `G`
And each of these would be characters stored into an array of characters.

Here's the chunk of code I've got working correctly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_INPUT_SIZE ( (sizeof(char)*96) + (sizeof(int)*48) )

int main () {

  char *input = malloc(MAX_INPUT_SIZE);

  printf("Example input:  1:E 2:C 2:C 2:C 8:D\n");
  printf("Your input:\n\n");

  fgets(input, MAX_INPUT_SIZE, stdin);

  // Removing newline
  if ( (strlen(input) > 0) && (input[strlen(input) - 1] == '\n') )
      input[strlen(input) - 1] = '\0';

  int i = 0;
  char *p = strtok(input, " ");
  char *array[MAX_PAIRS];

  while (p != NULL){
      array[i++] = p;
      p = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }

  // Checking the array
  int j = 0;
  for (j=0; j<i; j++) {
      printf("\n    %s", array[j]);
  }
```

And this code works just fine. Next is the code I'm currently working with:

```
  int k = 0;
  int l = 0;

  char *letter = malloc( sizeof(char) * (i * 2) );

  for (k=0; k<i; k++) {
      char *q = strtok(array[k], ":");

      while (q != NULL) {
          letter[l++] = q;
          q = strtok(NULL, ":");

      }
  }

  // Checking the array
  int m = 0;
  for (m=0; m<l; m++) {
      printf("\n    %c", letter[m]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

When I go to check the array, it prints a garbage symbol for each character I wanted to print. I don't understand what I did wrong here.

Comment: `letter[l++] = q;` --> `letter[l++] = *q;`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thank you very much. Still not exactly sure how the logic behind that works, as I mentioned in the answer below, but now my code works so I'm happy.

Comment: `*q`  is the character that the pointer points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`letter` is an array of `char`.
`q` is a `char*`.

Therefore, `letter[l++] = q` is not going to do what you want, as you're now storing a `char*` into a `char`; I would imagine the compiler would spit out some warning about truncation.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the explanation. This is probably the thousandth time I've mixed `char*` and `char` up.

EDIT: If you have the time, could you explain why I still had to put `*` before `q`? Because I originally defined both as `char *letter = . . .` and `char *q = . . .`. and up until now I've always thought that if the number of asterisks were the same, the math would work out.

Comment: One way to think about it, and this is something that lets you have a little fun (and/or annoy other coders), is that `array[index]` is turned into `*(array+index)`: you can see that it is being dereferenced there. I.e., while `letters` is a char*, `letters[l++]` is a char. The fun you can have (or used to, dunno if it still works), is that `index[array]`could give the same result as `array[index]`.